# Custom error messages in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, validation

I am trying to set custom error messages for invalid length of the following fields:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'required|min_length[4]');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|min_length[4]');
```

I want to set custom error messages for both of above fields, for example "Invalid name" and "invalid password".

I am trying following:

```
$this->form_validation->set_message('min_length', 'Invalid name');
```

But it will put same error message to both fields ie. 'Invalid name'.
How can I set second message (eg. Invalid Password), to the password field?)

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From CI [user_guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#settingerrors):

> If you include %s in your error
>   string, it will be replaced with the
>   "human" name you used for your field
>   when you set your rules.

```
$this->form_validation->set_message('min_length', 'Invalid %s');
```

`%s` will become "password" or "name" or whatever field name the min_length is set

Comment: I forgot to mention, i tried this but it doesnt work. Keeps printing default message.